Solutions to $(f(x)-f(y))^3=f\left(x^3\right)-f\left(y^3\right)$
I was wondering, if there are more solutions to the functional equations, than $f(x) = const$. Maybe someone has an idea of how to find all solutions (or all continuous solutions)?
Find all the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such, that for any $x$ and $y$ the following is true: $(f(x)-f(y))^3=f(x^3)-f(y^3).$
Here are some thoughts on this question (some of which are from comment section):
If we consider $f(0)$ to be equal to $0$, then we get $f(x^3) = (f(x))^3$.
From this, substituting $x = 1$ and $x = -1$, we get that both $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ are contained in ${-1; 0; 1}$.
Maybe, if use the idea, that $f(x^3) = (f(x))^3$, in the original equation, than we get $-3f(x)f(y)(f(x)-f(y))=0$ for every $x$ and $y$. Then, if there exists an $x$ for which $f(x)$ is not $0$, then for every $y$ either $f(y)=0$ or $f(x)=f(y)$. That concludes, that $f(x)$ has a two-number range ${0; 1}$ or ${0; -1}$ (if not $1$, or $-1$, then $f(x^3)$ is not $-1$, $0$ or $1$), or $f(x)=0$ for every $x$.
Considering that if $f(x)$ is an answer, than $-f(x)$ is also an answer, than $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$ for every $x$.
It seems, that $f(x^3) = (f(x))^3$ is sufficient for $(f(x)-f(y))^3=f(x^3)-f(y^3)$ to be true, so now we have an equation $f(x^3) = (f(x))^3$, where the range of $f$ is $0;1$.
From here, it is obvious, that an answer for an easier case, when $f(0)=0$ and there exists $t$ such, that $f(t)=1$ is any function $f$ which is equal to $0$ for all $x$ in $A$, where for each $x$ in $A$: $x^3$ is also in $A$, and otherwise is equal to $1$.
For a complete solution without preassumptions, we get:
any $f(x)$, which is equal to $a$ if $x$ is in $A$, where $A$ satisfies, that $x^3$ is also in $A$, and otherwise is equal to $a+1$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I leave my proof, let me know if there are some incorrect reasonings please.
The globally constant functions satisfy our equation, so we can suppose there are $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. We observe that
$$ (f(x)-f(y))^3=f(x^3)-f(y^3)=(f(x^3)-f(z^3))-(f(y^3)-f(z^3))=(f(x)-f(z))^3-(f(y)-f(z))^3=(f(x)-f(y))((f(x)-f(z))^2+(f(x)-f(z))(f(y)-f(z))+ (f(y)-f(z))^2)= (f(x)-f(y))(3f^2(z)-3f(z)(f(x)+f(y))+f^2(x)+f^2(y)+f(x)f(y))$$
we can divide by $f(x)-f(y)\neq 0$ to obtain
$$f^2(x)+f^2(y)-2f(x)f(y)=3f^2(z)-3f(z)(f(x)+f(y))+f^2(x)+f^2(y)+f(x)f(y)$$
so that
$$3(f(z)-f(x))(f(z)-f(y))=0, \qquad \forall z\in \mathbb R.$$
This means that it there exists a set $A$ for which
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}f(x) \qquad z \in A \\ f(y) \qquad   \ z \notin A\end{cases}$$
Let us study the set $A$. We observe that $f(x^3) \neq f(y^3)$ otherwise from the initial equation we would get $f(x)=f(y)$. This means that $f(x^3)=f(x), f(y^3)=f(y)$ or viceversa. The viceversa is not possibile otherwise $f(x^3)=f(y), f(y^3)=f(x)$ means
$$ (f(x)-f(y))^3=f(x^3)-f(y^3)=f(y)-f(x)=-(f(x)-f(y)) \implies f(x)=f(y).$$
Therefore we have $f(x^3)=f(x)$ for each $x\in \mathbb R$. This means that $A$ is a set closed under the cubing, and moreover
$$(f(x)-f(y))^3=f(x^3)-f(y^3)=f(x)-f(y) \implies f(x)-f(y)=\pm 1 \implies f(y)=f(x)\pm 1.$$
Thus $f$ depends only by $f(x)$, and it is a direct computation to see that functions as those we have obtained (with $A$ closed under cubing) satisfy our equation.
Then all the possible functions are the constant ones together with those of the kind
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}k \qquad z \in A \\ k\pm 1 \qquad   \ z \notin A\end{cases}$$
where $A$ is a set closed under cubing.

Closed under cubing, forwards and backwards, right?

Yeah exactly, it is so

@FedericoFallucca the solution seems to be correct) thank you a lot!

You're welcome :)
